# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library gstreamer-0.10

Tags: java, maven, gstreamer

I'm getting this issue while compiling the code below. I installed gstreamer for Windows and added development jar file to my IDE but I couldn't solve this problem, please help me.

```
import org.freedesktop.gstreamer.ElementFactory;
   import org.freedesktop.gstreamer.Gst;
   import org.freedesktop.gstreamer.State;
   import org.freedesktop.gstreamer.elements.PlayBin;  
   import org.freedesktop.gstreamer.lowlevel.GstNative;

   import java.io.File;

   public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {

            Gst.init("MyMediaPlayer", args);

            PlayBin playbin = new PlayBin("AudioPlayer");
            playbin.setVideoSink(ElementFactory.make("fakesink", "videosink"));
            playbin.setInputFile(new File("good.mp3"));

            playbin.setState(State.PLAYING);
            Gst.main();
            playbin.setState(State.NULL);
        }
        catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: are you using gradle?

Comment: Im using Maven to add JAR files to my project.

Comment: I don't know where I saw this error but I definitely have. Are you using Java 10 by any chance? Downgrade to the one that is supported by org.freedesktop.gstreamer.*

Comment: Still I get the same error.

Comment: This means the Windows native gstreamer libraries could not be located. They are either not installed, or set up incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Include directory for gstreamer library in the user environmental variable named 'Path'